# How to plot real-time relative volume on daily charts?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm using this simple script to plot the relative volume:

```
//@version=5
indicator('rVol')

length = input.int(30, 'Avg Length')
avg = ta.sma(volume, length)
rVol = volume / avg
plot(rVol, style=plot.style_columns)
```

Now I want to view it in real-time on the daily timeframe, so first of all I need to set the time range of the regular session:

```
time_range = input.session('0930-1600', 'Time')
```

Then I need to compute the cumulative volume in this range from the selected starting time to the current time.

Finally, I need to calculate the moving average of the cumulative volume in this precise range for the past x days. Something like this:

```
rVol = cVol / ta.sma(cVol, length)
```

I found these interesting scripts on here but I don't know how to adapt them in order to get what I need:

[How to create cumulative tick using Pine Script for TradingView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60835651/how-to-create-cumulative-tick-using-pine-script-for-tradingview)

[Showing Volume on the Daily chart in Premarket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70754079/showing-volume-on-the-daily-chart-in-premarket)

Can you please give me a hint?

Comment: Is "time_range" the whole trading session? If so it shouldn't be difficult at all, since the built-ins like volume return you real-time data on the last bar. Test it: if barstate.islast \n label.new(x=bar_index,y=close,color=color.blue,text=str.tostring(volume)). Then simply math.sum(volume, xDays) for the cum. Else you'd need to trim the data to your session, what I'd do by: volArray = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.ticker, '30', volume) // this imports the volume by 30mins as an array that you'd need to filter for your session afterwards and before cum. This solution is not elegant tho.

Comment: I understand your point and I think you're correct about real-time data on the last bar of the daily chart. I was confused by the fact that the cumulative volume shown on lower timeframes is different from the total volume on the daily charts, but as the user Bjorn Mistiaen said on the second link "security() on lower intervals doesn’t always return reliable data. Intrabar volume information on stocks, for example, will not match >1D volume, as data for both is reported differently by exchanges".

Comment: Anyway, I don't understand how to retrieve the cumulative volume in previous days, from the beginning of the session to the current time. This is necessary to calculate the average of the various cumulative volumes. For example, if now it's 14:30 and I know the current total volume of the day, how to know the cumulative volume of yesterday (and so on back in the past) from the opening time to "now" (14:30 in the example)?

Comment: Unfortunately that's exactly the point. You need LTF data in order to split the volume input. Volume alone is aggregate and can't help you. That's why my suggestion with the 30min LTF. Then you get an array of 30min vols every day. 14:30 is the 29th element in your array. So you could sum only the volume in a for loop the index of which is greater than 28 and lower than 32 (16:00). -"for [idx, vol] in ltf_vol_var"- That would repeat every day. Don't forget to store your calc with a "var" variable in order to keep the res over each bar